# Android ImageView - minWidth/minHeight has no effect when adjustViewBounds=true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to wrap the bigger image using adjustViewBounds, but while this is true minWidth/minHeight are not retained for smaller images and it takes up actual size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java;l=1119) for the "onMeasure()" method in *ImageView*, you will see that the minimum width and the minimum height do not come into play if either `resizeWidth == true` or `resizeHeight == true`. These resize variables are set to true if `adjustViewBounds` is also true.

You can introduce the use of `minWidth` and `minHeight` when `adjustViewBounds == true` with a custom *ImageView* such as follows:

```
class MyImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView(context, attrs) {

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(
            max(suggestedMinimumWidth, measuredWidth),
            max(suggestedMinimumHeight, measuredHeight)
        )
    }
}
```